# Editing Form Responses Programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google script that generates the edit URLs for each form response that is dumped into my spreadsheet. Is there a way to programatically change the response values as if I had actually opened the URL and changed the values manually?

For example, suppose someone submitted a form with the name field being "Sam." I want to be able to programmatically edit this response so that the value of the same field is "Samuel."

This is very easy to do manually via the form response edit url, however I am running into issues trying to do this in my scripts.

Comment: See the response to this question for [Editing Form Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638318/3354226) which links to necessary classes and also provides some other information which may be useful.

Comment: There is no "built-in" way in Apps Script to edit an existing Form response.  I previously assumed that there was a way to edit an existing Form response inside of a Form, but there is no "built-in" way.  There might be a way to make an HTTPS POST request, the same as the Form does, but currently I don't know how that POST request would be configured.  The POST request would be made with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`

Comment: You can copy the response, submit it again and delete the old one, but that's not editing. It's really annoying