# FILE_UPLOAD item type in Google Apps Script (GAS) for Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've seen [FILE_UPLOAD item type in google forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891218/file-upload-item-type-in-google-forms) regarding this topic.
My problem is related, but somewhat different--perhaps someone can recommend a workaround?

**Situation:** Using Google Forms as content submission and editing tool for certain kinds of "documents," with a specific form for each document.
**Objective:** copy an original form submission to create through GAS a NEW form submission with the same item responses.
This is based on a response in the original form submission indicating that a variant also needs to be created based on the original content.

Example: Another form entry is needed where the original content is translated to a different language (with first draft using google translate and then revised by native speaker using the Google form). In other cases, only portions of a long original submission need to be revised to create the variant document, where the revisions are made to the duplicated submission in the Google form.

Things are fine except where the form(s) have image upload options and I need to copy the FILE_UPLOAD content of the original form response back into the new scripted form submission.  But it appears required to specify the item type (e.g., .asTextItem(), .asCheckBoxItem(), etc.).  But there is no .asFileUploadItem() option (I tried using it), and therefore  an error is thrown, preventing the copy of FILE_UPLOAD content into the corresponding question item of the form.  I've tried using .asTextItem(), since the G-Drive address is just a text string (at least in the paired Google Sheet), but the Form won't accept that.  It seems (at least in our case) that the original file location *would* work for all variant duplicates that retain the same image, so copying the content (the G-Drive location of the image) should be fine, if GAS allowed me to do that.

Is there any workaround provided by Google, now that it is a year later than the previous post I found (above)?  Has anyone come up with a workable solution that might work for my case?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Your question is pretty convoluted.  I read through it several times and I think I see the problem but it would help if you would share a complete script that would help us to understand what you are  asking.  It would help me to see where you need to know where the asContentTypes? are that you are speaking about. For example where in  the script did you attempt to use asFileUploadItem()?  In the end questions with code are generally accepted much better.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for looking at this.  Before showing the "item type" problem in the FormResponse.withItemResponse() ste[p of FormResponse.submit().  I've encountered two more basic problems.

1) Can you confirm that form responses still cannot be edited programmatically?  Per 2018 comments in this post in stackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271395/editing-form-responses-programmatically

2) It appears that File_Upload  questions in Google forms cannot be edited even by the submitter using the edit URL for the submission.  Do you have experience with this?

Comment: @Cooper:   The FormResponse has an initial step of setting the item type,  e.g., qt = item.asTextItem()  which then is used ct = qt.createResponse( qr ); where qr is the response value. then FormResponse.withItemResponse(ct).  However, there is no  itemType for File_Upload (while there is for Text, Paragraph, Checkbox and others.)

Comment: "need to copy the FILE_UPLOAD content of the original form".  "FILE_UPLOAD content" is a file, what do you mean with "need to copy"? Do you mean that you want to access the image the user submitted and use it for something programmatically? In which format would you like to access this content? The URL of the file? As bytes?

Comment: @ziganotschka thanks for responding.  Since Google does not allow editing FILE_UPLOAD type questions in the form, I've determined for our process that images need to be uploaded separately to a folder and then that file link provided in the form (as a TEXT type), so that they can be replaced through the form with different images if desired.  So this question is "Closed" now for me, but I don't see an option to do that.  Thanks again to you and @Cooper; maybe this exchange will be useful to someone else dealing with the file_upload option in G-forms.