# Restrict a randomly generated code from changing when Editing a form response

Tags: google-apps-script

I am generating a reference number on `onFormSubmit(e)` and it gets sent to the email address provided by the submitter on the form, using the below code.

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{

    //generate a 8 digit alphanumeric number

    var unique_id = "";
    var possible = 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"; 

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        unique_id += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    //get form

    var form = FormApp.openById('1cE2COec2O7v-wpOI1GgTp8NnZRo8trePkmnqHPBGbCyw');

    //get spreadsheet

    var spreadsheetname = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Uk3yGEWeAKh9rAzLsnej1dg3bIddf9b3-R922u5OUNNs')

    //get last row

    var row =  spreadsheetname.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

    //get email column

    var column = spreadsheetname.getRange('B'+(row));

    //capture email

    var email = column.getValue()

    //set unique_id

    spreadsheetname.getRange('J' + (row)).getCell(1,1).setValue(unique_id).setFontStyle('italic')

    //send email 

    var sendemail = MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Worker Proposal Reference Number', 'Thank you for sumbmitting your worker proposal. Your worker proposal reference number is ' + unique_id + '.  Mention this reference number for making amendments to your worker proposal')
}
```

All of this works good. The problem arises when a form is edited. It still considers it as a "formSubmit" and generates a new reference code.

I'd like to keep the reference code unchanged on form submit.

I tried `onEdit(e)` with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope those IDs don't point to actual forms and spreadsheets :/

Comment: They do, but I am working on a dummy form, so no harm.

Comment: Probably see [Google Script for Forms: Edit Form Responses as soon as it is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637753), it's a fairly old question and response so things may have changed since then, but I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Every form response has a unique id associated with it. Assuming this `onFormSubmit(e)` trigger is a function of a script bound to a Form (and not a Spreadsheet) you can extract the form response id from the event object passed to the `onFormSubmit(e)` function.

[Here's a description of the event object's parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3).

So you can use the form response id instead of generating one yourself. See snippet below:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var uniqueId = e.response.getId();

    // do your other stuff
}
```

Comment: I replaced my `unique_id` generation code with your code
`var uniqueId = e.response.getId();`

    

I get this  error 

   TypeError: Cannot read property "response" from undefined.

Comment: @Paploo Is the script bound to a Spreadsheet or a Form? This only works if the script is bound to a Form.

Comment: Thank you for that tip, I will try this on a script bound to the form.