# Google Form edit response on submit with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am looking to make a form (which has a Sheets response) where staff will enter a number.  I would like to change this number and put something in front of it.  Example: they will enter 1234 and on the form it will enter it as AB-CDE-1234.  The first part will always be the same so I want to make it easier for them.  I am decent in scripting for Sheets but I have never done so with Forms and when submitting to sheets.

Is this even possible?  I am confused a little by what I saw in a search, I thought I would save myself time and see if it even if.

Comment: I just found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637753/edit-form-responses-as-soon-as-it-is-submitted#:~:text=A%20Form%20response%20inside%20of,an%20On%20Form%20Submit%20trigger.

Looks like you cannot in Forms but maybe in Sheets?  I am going to search for something in Sheets with response submit.

Answer (score 1):

I used these two functions to insert a similar sort of set of strings into the linked sheets.  In my case questions one through six are all short answer question.  In the event object x.values[0] is the time stamp and the rest are short answer questions and you can see below how the strings were inserted into the appriate row of the the linked sheet.

Code:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(x) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = x.range.getSheet();
  let o = [[1,2,3,4,5,6].map(i => `AB-${randomString(3)}-${x.values[i]}`)];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  sh.getRange(x.range.rowStart,x.range.columnStart + 1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
  
}

function randomString(n) {
  var chars='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 
  var s=chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*26.0));
  for(var i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    s+=chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*26.0));
  }
  return s.split('').sort(function(a,b){if(a==b){return 0;}else{return [-1,1][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];}}).join('');
}
```

The Ouput:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 69 | 10/18/2022 12:39:30 | AB-NDZ-one | AB-HSA-two | AB-UQD-three | AB-YNV-four | AB-BPM-five | AB-VHM-six |

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following script:

```
function addPrefix(e) {
  let r = e.range;
  const ss = r.getSheet();
  let values = e.values;
  let lastr = r.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(r.getLastRow(), 2).setValue("AB" + "-" + "CDE" + "-"  + values[1]);
  // I used 1 because I am changing the first value and 2 because that is the column
  // where it is located.
  // You can modify the script to randomize the "AB" and "CDE values if needed"
}
```

With the `event object` you can collect some information related to the form submission such as the values of the responses, the range of the spreadsheet where they were added, the spreadsheet that they were added to, etc.

Remember to add the `on form submit` installable trigger to your script as defined below:

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [Form submit object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#:%7E:text=10-,Form%20submit%20(installable),-Caution%3A%20Make)
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#:%7E:text=Send%20feedback-,Event%20Objects,-bookmark_border)
- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure this out.

In sheets, you can make any function and attach it to the trigger "On form submit".  It will run after a response is submitted, now I just have to work on getting variables and concatenating them.